# How do I deal with falling floor when fitting a kitchen?

Tags: kitchens, leveling

In UK we typically have a 15cm-17cm gap under melamine-faced chipboard kitchen units,  then cover with a plinth clipped on to the feet.

I'm putting in a kitchen and the floor drops a good inch over a 3 metre span. Should I put the units in parallel to the floor, or put them in level and have an inch taper in the plinth?

Not really viable to level the floor as it would affect floors throughout the house.

Answer (score 6):

If you put the units in parallel to the floor then your working surface slopes or you have steps in it. Neither are good.

Have the taper in the plinth.

In my case, I levelled the floor.